# Salesforce integration with Hybris

Tags: wsdl

I have a hybris web app that needs to search through a Salesforce database and display the results. How do I achieve this functionality using Saleforce APIs.

PS. Clearly I'm new to Salesforce and would only like a high level explanation.

Comment: yes you can use Salesforce API for that purpose.

Comment: You'll have to learn the APIs, figure out which fits best for your purposses and then consume them.  Start here : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Integration

Comment: @Deepak Chandran I also have the same requirement to integrate Hybris with salesforce. Can you suggest any UI for Hybris?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get to know the APIs, figure out which fits best for your purposses and then consume them. How to do that from Hybris is best asked at a more general developer site such as stackoverflow or any Hybris specific forum.

For the salesforce APIs you can start here : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Integration